# Figure out which Angular component issues the error during Karma test

Tags: angular, karma-runner

When running my Karma tests, I get lots of errors (which are in fact warnings) like this:

```
ERROR: 'NG0304: 'fa-icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'fa-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'fa-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
```

Now, this is easy to fix once you know which component complains about the unknown element. The problem is the application has dozens of them and Karma's output **doesn't provide any clue** as to where the problem arises.

How can I find out which component causes the error, without needing to selectively run tests against each of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that in recent Karma versions (I'm using Karma v6.4.0) this has finally been resolved:

```
ERROR: 'NG0304: 'fa-icon' is not a known element (used in the 'ApiKeyManagerComponent' component template):
1. If 'fa-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
2. If 'fa-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
```

The addition of `(used in the 'ApiKeyManagerComponent' component template)` is exactly what I was after.